# Button styling not not respecting styleName=""

Tags: shoutem

I am using the latest install of ShoutemUI 0.21.3 and RN 0.42.2. All buttons just have a white background. I am not using Shoutem Themes right now. I have tried `styleName="confirmation"` and still just a white button and no border. Am I missing something?

Here is the code on the left and the results on the right in the simulator.
[image]

Here is a screenshot of my imports.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The UI package has a `theme.js` file with all these `styleName`'s. In order to utilize it, you need `@shoutem/theme` installed. It's a dependency of `@shoutem/ui`.

Furthermore, the `dark` `styleName` is obsolete. You should utilize `secondary` instead for the desired effect.

Comment: I do have `@shoutem/theme` installed and I am importing `import { StyleProvider } from '@shoutem/theme';`. `secondary` works great! `confirmation` does not, has this changed as well?